# Execute Oracle stored procedure from ArcSDESQLExecute

Tags: arcpy, enterprise-geodatabase, sql, oracle-dbms, stored-procedure

I'm attempting to execute an Oracle 12c stored procedure using [ArcSDESQLExecute](http://desktop.arcgis.com/en/arcmap/10.3/analyze/arcpy-classes/arcsdesqlexecute.htm):

import arcpy

```
egdb_conn = arcpy.ArcSDESQLExecute(r"Database Connections\con1.sde")

sql = '''execute update_sle (2500000, 500000)'''
egdb_return = egdb_conn.execute(sql)

print "Complete."
```

However, I'm getting the following error:

```
Message File Name   Line    Position    
Traceback               
    <module>    <module1>   21      
    execute C:\Program Files (x86)\ArcGIS\Desktop10.3\ArcPy\arcpy\arcobjects\arcobjects.py  27      
AttributeError: ArcSDESQLExecute: StreamExecute ArcSDE Extended error 900 ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement
```

**Question:**

How can I execute an Oracle stored procedure by using ArcSDESQLExecute?

---

**Notes:**

1. The python script executes successfully on `select` queries. Therefore, I know the script works.
2. I can execute the procedure from SQL Developer successfully. Therefore, I know the procedure works.
3. I tried `SET FEEDBACK OFF` but got an error. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10720751/what-is-the-oracle-equivalent-of-sql-servers-set-nocount-on).
4. Related question/answer [here](https://community.esri.com/thread/190552-arcsdesqlexecute-arcpy-for-stored-proc), but I think it's for SQL Server.

Comment: Did you try using `call` instead of `execute` ? https://community.esri.com/thread/3887#comment-118410

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As mentioned in [this thread](http://community.esri.com/thread/3887#comment-118410), replacing `EXECUTE` with `CALL` can resolve this issue - sometimes at least.

This SO [response](https://stackoverflow.com/a/34776295/125400) addresses the issue more generally, suggesting it's not peculiar to ArcGIS.

Comment: For what it's worth, `CALL` also works in MS Access [pass-through queries](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/process-sql-on-a-database-server-by-using-a-pass-through-query-b775ac23-8a6b-49b2-82e2-6dac62532a42).